# Jquery fallback for replace string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that work for modern browser that support jQuery. but sometime there always visitor who use browser that are very outdated and does not support jQuery.

The code purpose is to search and replace english word with UTF8 Chinese letters.

Any idea how do I tune this code to make it work for older browser.

**Thanks!**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function replaceText(selector, text, newText, flags) {
  var matcher = new RegExp(text, flags);
  $(selector).each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.children().length)
       $this.text($this.text().replace(matcher, newText));
  });
}

function replaceAllText() {
        replaceText('*', 'Due', '总数', 'g');
        replaceText('*', 'Pin', '配套PIN码', 'g');
        replaceText('*', 'No.', '编号', 'g');
   }

$(document).ready(replaceAllText);
$('html').ajaxStop(replaceAllText);

</script>
```

Comment: Which browser version didn't work with your jQuery script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are versions of jQuery that support browsers right the way back to (and including) IE6. If you need to support obsolete browsers, use the latest in the jQuery v1.x line. It sounds like you're using jQuery v2.x or even jQuery 3.x, which only support newer browsers.

---

Side note: Your `replaceText` method isn't handling special regular expression characters correctly, and is much more complicated than it needs to be. Here's a simpler version that handles special characters correctly:

```
function replaceText(selector, regex, newText) {
    $(selector).not("script, style").each(function() {
        var node;
        for (node = this.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(regex, newText);
            }
        }
    });
}

function replaceAllText() {
    // Note that I'm defining the regular expression here, not in `replaceText`
    // It's too easy not to realize that you're doing a regex and include a
    // character that is special in regular expressions (like the `"."` in
    // `"No."` and end up matching things incorrectly.
    replaceText('*', /Due/g, '总数');
    replaceText('*', /Pin/g, '配套PIN码');
    replaceText('*', /No\./g, '编号');
}
```

```js
function replaceText(selector, regex, newText) {
    $(selector).not("script, style").each(function() {
        var node;
        for (node = this.firstChild; node; node = node.nextSibling) {
            if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(regex, newText);
            }
        }
    });
}

function replaceAllText() {
    // Note that I'm defining the regular expression here, not in `replaceText`
    // It's too easy not to realize that you're doing a regex and include a
    // character that is special in regular expressions (like the `"."` in
    // `"No."` and end up matching things incorrectly.
    replaceText('*', /Due/g, '总数');
    replaceText('*', /Pin/g, '配套PIN码');
    replaceText('*', /No\./g, '编号');
}

replaceAllText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Due
  <div>
    Stuff
    <div>
      Pin No. Pin Due
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note we used the DOM directly for some things; in this case, it's just as simple as the jQuery code. But if you prefer to use jQuery as much as possible, `replaceText` changes to:

```
function replaceText(selector, regex, newText) {
    $(selector).not("script, style").each(function() {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, newText);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```js
function replaceText(selector, regex, newText) {
    $(selector).not("script, style").each(function() {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, newText);
            }
        });
    });
}

function replaceAllText() {
    // Note that I'm defining the regular expression here, not in `replaceText`
    // It's too easy not to realize that you're doing a regex and include a
    // character that is special in regular expressions (like the `"."` in
    // `"No."` and end up matching things incorrectly.
    replaceText('*', /Due/g, '总数');
    replaceText('*', /Pin/g, '配套PIN码');
    replaceText('*', /No\./g, '编号');
}

replaceAllText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Due
  <div>
    Stuff
    <div>
      Pin No. Pin Due
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Finally: We can make the whole thing more efficient by making **one** pass through the DOM instead of three, using a regular expression with an *alternation* (`this|that|theother`) and then looking up the matched text in a mapping of old to new:

```
function replaceAllText() {
    var replacements = {
        "Due": "总数",
        "Pin": "配套PIN码",
        "No.": "编号"
    };
    var regex = /(?:Due|Pin|No\.)/g;
    $("*:not(script):not(style)").each(function() {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, function(text) {
                    return replacements[text];
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```js
function replaceAllText() {
    var replacements = {
        "Due": "总数",
        "Pin": "配套PIN码",
        "No.": "编号"
    };
    var regex = /(?:Due|Pin|No\.)/g;
    $("*:not(script):not(style)").each(function() {
        $(this).contents().each(function() {
            if (this.nodeType === 3) {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(regex, function(text) {
                    return replacements[text];
                });
            }
        });
    });
}

replaceAllText();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  Due
  <div>
    Stuff
    <div>
      Pin No. Pin Due
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```